# discord.js How to get channel ID By name?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a `discord.js` bot and I need to find the #counting channel after making it.

I have tried this code:

```js
if (command === 'init') {
 try {
  msg.guild.channels.create('counting');

  var countChannel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(
   (channel) => channel.name === 'counting'
  );

  msg.channel.send(`Created <#${countChannel}>`);
 } catch (err) {
  msg.channel.send(`Error: **${err}**`);
 }
}
```

I don't have a clue as to why this is returning `undefined`.

Any fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GuildChannelManager.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) returns a `Promise`, and passes the created channel as an argument.

```js
if (command === 'init') {
 msg.guild.channels
  .create('counting')
  .then((countChannel) => {
   msg.channel.send(`Created <#${countChannel.id}>`);
  })
  .catch((err) => msg.channel.send(`Error: **${err}**`));
}
```

---

As for the reason you were getting your error, the script was simply running too fast, and tried to find the channel before it even finished being created.

Comment: Glad I could help :)